# C2DM - problems when Using the new AuthToken after I get Update-Client-Auth

Tags: android-c2dm

Im developing push notification server that works with google's C2DM service.

When I get "Update-Client-Auth" in the response header , I replace the previous token , for use on the next push notification.

When I send notification right after I got new token , it fails - 
with the response  - "InvalidRegistration"

My questions are ?

1. How to avoid this ? Should I wait before I use the new token ?
2. When do I need to start using the new token ? is the  expiration date included on header    should be used ?

I havent found this phenomenon mentioned anywhere.

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with your Auth. token.

"InvalidRegistration" means that the Registration token of the device to which you're sending the C2DM Message is invalid. You should make sure that the device sends you an updated Registration Id/token if it changes (apparently it can).

Clear your server cache/DB and start again by getting the device to re-register with Google and then send the registration token to your server and see what happens.

Of course, I'm guessing you don't have lots of registrations in your DB, if you're still in development...

Regards,

Mark

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. When I re register for new token , I get a token that I can use. My question should be : When to start to use the updated token that I get from the service (Update-Client-Auth) ?       The previous token is still valid , and the new one is not (not yet ?).

Comment: Now I see that after I re register for new AuthToken  , using the new token to send a push notification returns the response   "InvalidRegistration".    Any ideas ?

Comment: Anyway  I no longer making an effort to make these registrations work for me , because Im moving now to working with GCM (that replaces the previous C2DM). With this service I don't need to register for getting the token fo the server.